# How to extract a model stored as a pickle file

Tags: python, pickle

I had previously stored the model as a pickle file but now I am unable to access it. Could you please help me with this? I need the trained model to be shown to my mentor who has asked me to show it in a demo. I tried the below method but it gave the error but the file does exit. I can see it.

```py
with open('rand_forest.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in  with open('rand_forest.pkl', 'rb') as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rand_forest.pkl'

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data? Are you sure this is `R` or `python`?

Comment: the model has been developed and stored as a pickle. It was done in python. I will edit it

Comment: How was the model generated - sklearn? What else? The model file ain't there!

Comment: I had used sklearn to develop the model. The model file is saved locally on my system

Comment: probably a filepath issue, try using the absolute path to the file

Comment: I tried it but it gave error as invalid argument `mdl = open('D:\Data Backup 18.12.21\python\rand_forest.pkl', 'rb')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\Data Backup 18.12.21\\python\rand_forest.pkl'`

Comment: I rectified the issue by adding r in front of the file path. Thanks

Comment: Clearly not a file format problem at this point. First get the correct path to your file. Also be warned that deserialising pickle file is not safe. Only open pickle files you can trust.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The pickle file which I am trying to access is created by myself.